# Data sharing via stack between publisher and consumer thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency

I have a publisher thread and a consumer thread. They share data via a `std::stack<Data *>`. The publisher simply push() the pointer and consumer simply pop() the pointer, use it and call delete on it. Since there is only single thread publishing pointers one at a time, and one thread consuming pointers, is there any need to synchronize the stack? Keep in mind that stack is only storing pointers. Publisher pushes pointer only when Data() is fully  constructed.

Comment: Yes, you have to synchronise. `push()` and `pop()` are not atomic operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Failure to synchronize on non-`const` methods of containers in `std` namespace is undefined behavior.

Neither `push` nor `pop` is `const` on the underlying container of a `stack`.  So two threads are both writing to the state of the underlying container of the `stack`.

A way to think about it is that both are, at the very least, going to have to fight over the count of the number of elements in the `stack`: one is trying to increase it, the other is trying to decrease it.  (There are other problems, but that one should convince you that both are writing to the state of the `stack`)

Answer (score 1):

The `std::stack<Data*>` instance will need to have access synchronized as more than one thread can be modifying it (via `pop()` and `push()`) but the elements contained in it do not as only a single thread can be operating on an element at any one time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a need to synchronize access to the stack, because `std::stack` class does not guarantee that any operation is atomic and it is possible, that `push()`, `top()` and `pop()` will interleave.